# Include 0 counts as frequency and create new columns

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

suppose I have a data.frame

```
df = data.frame ( 
    sample = c ( "s1","s2","s2"), 
    drug = c( "drug2" , "drug1", "drug2")
)

  sample  drug
1     s1 drug2
2     s2 drug1
3     s2 drug2
```

Is there any easy way to create a table counting all instances of drugs including zero hits?

ideally, something like this.

```
samle drug1 drug2
1    s1     0     1
2    s2     1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

What about base R's good old `table`?

```
table(df)
#      drug
#sample drug1 drug2
#s1     0     1
#s2     1     1
```

Or to get a `matrix` output

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
#   drug1 drug2
#s1     0     1
#s2     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `dplyr`. The latest version of `dplyr` (0.8.0.1 as of this writing) has a `.drop=FALSE` option for grouping variables that preserves empty groups. For the preservation of empty groups to work, the grouping columns must all be factor class:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  # Convert grouping columns to factor if they aren't already
  mutate_if(is.character, factor) %>% 
  group_by(sample, drug, .drop=FALSE) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  spread(drug, n)
```

> ```
>   sample drug1 drug2
> 1 s1         0     1
> 2 s2         1     1
> ```

Or, to keep the output in "long" format for further processing, stop before the `spread`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, factor) %>% 
  group_by(sample, drug, .drop=FALSE) %>% 
  tally
```

> ```
>   sample drug      n
> 1 s1     drug1     0
> 2 s1     drug2     1
> 3 s2     drug1     1
> 4 s2     drug2     1
> ```

The code above will ensure that all empty group combinations are preserved. However, if you're going to spread the data to a "wide" format table, then we can take care of the missing groups in the `spread` step without worrying about whether `group_by` preserves empty groups:

> ```
> df %>% 
>   group_by(sample, drug) %>% 
>   tally %>% 
>   spread(drug, n, fill=0)
> ```